# Excel VBA Macro: Search/Find /Case/Lookup ? Down one column find then search again in on the next column then output data from 3rd column

Tags: vba, excel

Hi is it possible to run a VB script to perform search in an array of 10 columns 16000 rows, Look for data partialy matching data from a cell of which there will be 24 identical data in column C, but in column D each there are numbers from 1 to 24 relating to D, compare that number with cell when it finds it take date from column G and H and output it somewhere else. so I think it goes something like this.

```
Sub LookupPCI01()


Dim pf As Worksheet, pi As Worksheet, eq As Worksheet, ei As Worksheet, WS As Worksheet, exw As Worksheet
Dim Rws As Long, I As Long, Rng As Range, c As Range, cr
Dim FindPCI As String, OT As String, CT As String
Dim vArray As Variant


    Set pf = Sheets("PAR Form")
    Set pi = Sheets("PAR_import")
    Set eq = Sheets("Equipment details")
    Set im = Sheets("IMAC Form")
    Set ei = Sheets("Eq_import")
    Set exw = Sheets("PCI_CW_EX")




    Dim FirstAddress As String


    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

      vArray = Array(Left(pf.Cells(cr, 13), 6))

        With exw
        Rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "C"), .Cells(Rws, "C"))


       If .Offset(0, 1) = pf.Cells(38) Then

        For I = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)

             Set Rng = .Find(What:=vArray(I), _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlFormula, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)

            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                FirstAddress = Rng.Address
                Do
                    pi.Cells(cr + 14, 3).Value = Rng.Offset(0, 4).Value
                    pi.Cells(cr + 14, 4).Value = Rng.Offset(0, 5).Value
                    Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
                Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
            End If
        Next I
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It will help greatly to give a visual representation of the current data, and what you want to have done with the data.  I personally find the text description of the problem very hard to follow.

Comment: Please describe your question. Doesn't your code work as you want? Do you have an error message - what, at which line? Please post only part of the code only which is relevant for the question (e.g. You mention only two worksheets but you have six sheets defined in the code)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt responses, i will upload sample data now, the code errors on  if offset (0,1),

Comment: The file is here [URL=http://wikisend.com/download/975514/P03 - MacroTest66.xlsm]P03 - MacroTest66.xlsm[/URL]

Comment: I am currently only have limited information in pf to export about PCI-CDCW-D10-AB:***** to D02-AH:*****
I want it too look up with in exw row C, then compare port name currently 2 then copy the info in G an h PCI-CDCW-D02-AH:07>24 to D10-AB:01>18= G  and  8 = H

Comment: Script is in last Sub  LookupPCI01() of PARImport Module

Comment: `exw` is a worksheet - it doesn't have an `Offset()` method.  You need a Range object qualifier there.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub LookupPCI01()

Dim pf As Worksheet, pi As Worksheet, eq As Worksheet, ei As Worksheet, WS As Worksheet, exw As Worksheet, op As Worksheet
Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range, c As Range, cr
Dim ConTrue(1 To 3) As Integer
Dim ExtractInfo()
Dim CountArrayRow As Integer

Set pf = Sheets("PAR Form")
Set pi = Sheets("PAR_import")
Set eq = Sheets("Equipment details")
Set im = Sheets("IMAC Form")
Set ei = Sheets("Eq_import")
Set exw = Sheets("PCI_CW_EX")
Set op = Sheets("OutP")

On Error Resume Next

ConTrue(1) = 1
ConTrue(2) = 5
ConTrue(3) = 9

CountArrayRow = 0

ReDim ExtractInfo(1 To ConTrue(3), 1 To 1)


With exw
     Rws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
 Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, ConTrue(1)), .Cells(Rws, ConTrue(3)))
End With


For i = 1 To Rws
   If exw.Cells(i, ConTrue(1) + 2).Value Like pi.Cells(16, 3) Then
     CountArrayRow = CountArrayRow + 1

''Redim everytime Finds that connection
ReDim Preserve ExtractInfo(1 To ConTrue(3), 1 To CountArrayRow)

''Copy to the Array
    For J = 1 To ConTrue(3)
       ExtractInfo(J, CountArrayRow) = exw.Cells(i, J).Value
      Next J
     End If
    Next i    

''result of the array 
    For i = 1 To 9
     For J = 1 To (CountArrayRow)
      op.Cells(i, J) = ExtractInfo(i, J)
     Next J
    Next

''search the value 02

For i = 1 To CountArrayRow
    If CInt(pf.Cells(2, 39).Value) = ExtractInfo(i, 4) Then

     End If
Next

'PCI Export

Dim PT As Integer
PT = pi.Cells(16, 4).Value

    pi.Cells(16, 3).Value = op.Cells(3, PT)
    pi.Cells(50, 1).Value = op.Cells(7, PT)
    pi.Cells(50, 2).Value = op.Cells(8, PT)

End Sub
```